# How to combine CSVs with different columns?

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, csvhelper, c#-6.0

I have multiple CSV files and I need to combine all of them into 1 CSV file.

So, for example:

**1.csv** has data like below:

| Roll no | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Abc |
| 2 | xyz |

**2.csv** has data like below:

| Name | Date | Score | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mno | 20-12-2023 | 450 |  |
| Pqr | 21-12-2023 | 480 |  |

and I want the combined CSV file for this data like below:

**Master.csv**

| Roll no | Name | Date | Score | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Abc |  |  |  |
| 2 | xyz |  |  |  |
|  | Mno | 20-12-2023 | 450 |  |
|  | Pqr | 21-12-2023 | 480 |  |

if a specific column is not present in a CSV file then leave it as empty.

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: How would you do it if you had to do it with a pen and paper? First you get the 
distinct union of the columnnames of both, then copy row by row, putting each item to the appropriate column.

Comment: Is this a one- time thing where you know the columns of each file in advance or do you need it more generic where input is an arbitrary number of files with arbitrary sets of columns?

Comment: i need it more generic way because this is just example

Comment: Explain the actual case then. You can use CsvHelper to read both files into separate object lists, combine them with LINQ's Concat and export them again. Or you can load them into separate DataTables using CsvDataReader, merge them with [DataTable.Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge?view=net-8.0) and export the result

Comment: read in csv1 read in csv2. get names of all columns. set an order for the columns. create the master csv. go through data of csv1 and write into master csv, leave empty for columns csv1 doesnt have. same for csv2. save master csv. Done. thats pseudocode for what you wanna do. try that and ask again if you run into any specific problems

Answer (score 0):

You could read the two files as `csv2.GetRecords<dynamic>()` and get the dynamic properties to create a new `dynamic` list with a union of the two sets of headings.

```cs
void Main()
{
    using var reader1 = new StringReader("Roll no,Name\n1,ABC\n2,xyz");
    using var csv1 = new CsvReader(reader1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var records1 = csv1.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();

    using var reader2 = new StringReader("Name,Date,Score,Remarks\nMno,20-12-2023,450,\nPqr,21-12-2023,480,");
    using var csv2 = new CsvReader(reader2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var records2 = csv2.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();
    
    IDictionary<string, object> properties1 = (IDictionary<string, object>)records1.First();
    IDictionary<string, object> properties2 = (IDictionary<string, object>)records2.First();
    
    var headings = properties1.Keys.Union(properties2.Keys);
    
    var results = ConvertRecords(records1, headings);
    results.AddRange(ConvertRecords(records2, headings));
    
    using var csvOut = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    csvOut.WriteRecords(results);
}

public List<dynamic> ConvertRecords(IEnumerable<dynamic> records, IEnumerable<string> headings)
{
    var results = new List<dynamic>();

    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        var result = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
        var item = (IDictionary<string, object>)record;

        foreach (var heading in headings)
        {
            if (item.ContainsKey(heading))
            {
                result.Add(heading, item[heading]);
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(heading, string.Empty);
            }
        }

        results.Add(result);
    }
    
    return results;
}
```